# Crystal report: Grow details section left to right

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

i am using using crystal report for reporting. I want to grow my 'Details' section left to right side instead of top to bottom side. I want my report like below:

**First page**

> Roll-> 1     2     3     4     5     6
>
> Phy    78     65    34    67   89    90 Chem   56     67    87    65
>   54    43 Math   67     89    34    67   78    90

**Second page**

> Roll-> 7     8     9     10
>
> Phy    78     65    34    67 Chem   56     67    87    65 Math   67
>   89    34    67

And so on. How can i design my crystal report for this reporting. Please anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In section expert, details section, check "Format with multiple columns". Then choose "Layout" tab, set required detail area width and choose printing direction "Across, then down".

Answer (score 0):

Use CrossTab Reports

subject name for rows, Roll number for Columns and Marks form summary

Hope this help for future inquiries, though it is too late :)